# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using MySQL and I am getting this error in Eclipse while I am trying to connect my code using JDBC. I am using the version 8.0.20 of workbench

### Exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)
```

### Code snippet

```java
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jamiahamdard", "root", "root");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from students");
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
finally {
    try {
        con.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, can anyone help me out what should I do?

Comment: i am using mysql workbench and i am getting this error in eclipse  while i am trying to connect my code using jdbc so can anyone help me out what should i do i am using the version 8.0.20 of workbench

Comment: Can you show your code to connect to the database?

Comment: yes of course but can you tell what went wrong why i am getting this error?

Comment: Connection con = null;
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
 con = DriverManage.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jamiahamdard",
       "root", "root");
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from  students");
   while (rs.next())
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2));
  }catch (SQLException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  } finally {
   try {
    con.close();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @Anuy Goyal Please, try to edit your initial question and add the code to this question. You have more formatting possibilities in the question, see [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you already seen this [post](https://coderanch.com/t/709460/databases/connect-SQL-Database-Java-Eclipse). The Original Poster (OP) had a similar problem and could change it by reinstalling eclipes and an additional time configuration.

Comment: i have done everthing like i have reinstalled the eclipse as well as mysql workbench also but unable to find the solution yet so i requst you tell me what to do in this case

Comment: According to the stacktrace, you're running the MySQL Connector/J application `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump`, not your own application. See the duplicate.

Comment: so what should i do in this case @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: Make sure you run the right application. This line in the stacktrace makes clear you're not running your own application: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)`

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Actually i have downloaded it from maven repositories MySQL Connector/J application

Comment: Yes, you need MySQL Connector/J to connect, but whatever you're doing right now is not running **your application**, but an application within the MySQL Connector/J library.

Comment: @Mark Rottevee Actually i am a beginner in this so can you tell steps to do and resolve this problem

Comment: Look at the duplicate

Comment: yes i saw all the duplicates and try to resolve it but the result is same .

Comment: @Mark Rottevee Thanks a lot you made my error clear god bless you bro

Comment: @rene thanks the error is solved